# Number sign/hash/Pound sign/# in Keycloack redirect URL instead of ampersand (&) or question mark (?)

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have Keycloak running locally in a container (https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/keycloak). I configure a realm and a client. Redirect from my web app to Keycloak login page works. My web app sends me to `http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=my-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Flogin%3Ffrom_redirect%3D1&state=bd4fcd5f-b46e-4c90-b42f-3b34e852fc26&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=2b9f94b6-cfd7-4054-881d-765f2bf62460`. The redirect URI parameter passed to Keycloak is correct: `http://localhost:4200/login?from_redirect=1&state=bd4fcd5f-b46e-4c90-b42f-3b34e852fc26&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=2b9f94b6-cfd7-4054-881d-765f2bf62460`. After I successfully login, Keycloak redirects me back to my web app but the URI is `http://localhost:4200/login?from_redirect=1#state=bd4fcd5f-b46e-4c90-b42f-3b34e852fc26&session_state=6b952844-6fd2-4e2a-bd01-41678669bbe6&code=f7e3725e-bf89-4db4-b969-84bb5c38b795.6b952844-6fd2-4e2a-bd01-41678669bbe6.2b541259-a8bb-404d-876f-5ef58499d055`. Note that it has a `#` instead of `&` in `from_redirect=1#state=bd4fcd5f`. How can I fix this in Keycloak?

Comment: Access Token Response in OAuth are passed as fragment component (starting with #) and not query parameters (starting with ?)!